# Angular - dynamic Component

Tags: angular

I was reading this Malcoded article https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-dynamic-components and this couple sentences got me like `:|`

> Because of the way angular works, it has to know about every component
>   at buildtime.
>
> That means that the component has to be defined in the same project or
>   has to be imported into an angular module of the project.

Say I have a TS file which contains an Angular Component (with its template) and all dependencies can be satisfied. 
Why couldn't I require that module at run time and ask Angular to instantiate the class?

My goal would be to let a user of my application code his own Component, then download and integrate it from a remote API.
Am I looking too far away? Is this something not feasable at all?

Comment: I have deleted my answer, it wasn't as useful as I thought, here is a post which might be of interest: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373#issuecomment-453006158

Comment: The approach might not work: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8275

Comment: You can use lazy loading https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: It's not just about the dependencies, the code also needs to be compiled. Without a compiler, that's impossible. And the compiler has been stripped from the build code when using AOT. So the only way to get it working would be to create a JIT build(using `ng build`). The down side of that is that the app will be a lot slower and the build size will be very large(due to the compiler being included and all the code being uncompiled at runtime).

Comment: @enf0rcer I'll manually create and provide the JIT compiler. Then download and compile the Module using SystemJS, and then include it using `ViewChild`/`ViewContainerRef`, setting its properties

Comment: @LppEdd I don't know about SystemJS, I only did it once in a @angular/cli project. But that does sound like the proper way to go. Just a heads up, I was never able to get the JIT compiler working aside a AOT compiled project. I don't remember what limitation I faced, but I think it was related to the JIT compiler being only available in low level angular code that gets stripped when compiling using AOT.

Comment: @enf0rcer you need to manually provide an instance of JitCompilerFactory